# R: collapse rows and change value according to condition in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, row

I have a dataset:

`structure(list(num = c(12L, 12L), code = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), ranking = c(2414.5, 2414.5), bottom = c(-0.0153795976572657, 
-0.00651997615327495), previous = c(0.00121016455715892, 
-0.000166609624290187), of_all_previous = c(-0.000570973882726524, 
-0.000771377162183913)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")`

I would like to collapse the two rows according to `num` and `ranking` since they are the same but change `code` according to conditions where the two rows' values for columns `bottom`, `previous`, and `of_all_previous` should be compared sequentially (meaning: if they are equal then move on to the next column as in `bottom` -> `previous` -> `of_all_previous`) and choose the `code` that has the higher value.

In the case of the sample data provided, `code` `b` because `-0.0065199761532749503 > -0.0153795976572656777` in the `bottom` column.

If they were equal then `previous` columns would have to be looked at.

I think that maybe `dplyr` can use the `%>%` to collapse rows but I cannot find how to change rows at the same time according to conditionality.

I expect the output to look something like this:

```
            num   code ranking 
1            12    a  2414
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry its actually  `b` not `J.NKEN`

Comment: can you show the expected output format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach might be to `group_by` both `num` and `ranking` to look at rows that have same values and need to be collapsed.

Then, would `arrange` (sort) in descending order the columns where comparisons are made, including `bottom` `previous` and `of_all_previous`. When this is done, the higher row in the sorted data will consider the columns in order for comparison when there are ties.

Finally, you can create a `final_code` with the `first(code)` based on the sorting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(num, ranking) %>%
  arrange(-bottom, -previous, -of_all_previous) %>%
  mutate(final_code = ifelse(n() > 1, as.character(first(code)), as.character(code))) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(num, code, ranking)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, we can pivot to 'long' format and `slice` the row

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = bottom:of_all_previous) %>%
  group_by(num, ranking, name) %>%
  slice(which.max(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  slice(1)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#    num code  ranking name      value
#  <int> <fct>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#1    12 b       2414. bottom -0.00652
```

Comment: There maybe be a case the values in the first column `bottom` will be equal, if so I would like the code to test the rest of the columns as well. Is this possible?